# Disable Laravel session encryption

Tags: php, encryption, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using database driver for sessions in Laravel 4, which means the sessions are saved in the database. I think encrypting the session data in this situation is not necessary and could slow down my application.
I want to know is this true? And if it is, how can I disable session encryption?

Comment: Encryption is necessary to stop a site admin from being your worst nightmare hacker.

Comment: I'm using Laravel with default session handling (I've only modded the configuration so they're stored in Redis) but they're not encrypted at all.... so what have you changed to encrypt your sessions?

Comment: @RiggsFolly if some one can see my sessions information in database, so probably he can see everything else there (which are not encrypted), and I think my session data is not more important than other data that exists in my database.

Comment: @MarkBaker when I use default driver (which is file), session is not encrypted

Answer (score 0):

@Hamid,

By default the session files are stored in the server unencrypted whether it is file or database. And the question about encrypting these contents arise only if you think that some third party who has got access to your servers will look into these contents. If that is the case then you got to be concerned about more challenges because of the third party being able to access the server. Additionally you may consider encrypting these contents but that would affect the performance of the system if you have a large user base.

Over the network you should be taking care of securing the session id by applying HTTPOnly and Secure flags or even better session handling measures(Refer [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management)) to prevent session hijacking, fixation and so on.

To conclude, you may do this if you are building critical applications or to meet any regulatory compliance, generally it is not done.

Comment: Can you tell me why my sessions are encrypted by default? How can I change that?

Comment: @Hamid, It is not encrypted by default. You can check this by looking at app/storage/sessions folder. This is where the session files are stored when ever any user activity is stored in the session, you can see this directory having files containing that user details.